# SELECTing only one copy of a row with a specific key that is coming from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL so bear with me. I am returning data from multiple tables. Followed is my SQL (let me know if there is a better approach):

```
SELECT [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description], [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate], [Application].[AppName], [SupportCatagory].[Catagory], [DailyTaskHours].[PK_DailyTaskHours],n [NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] 
FROM [NonScrumStory], [DailyTaskHours], [Application], [SupportCatagory] 
WHERE ([NonScrumStory].[UserId] = 26) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] = [DailyTaskHours].[NonScrumStoryId]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[CatagoryId] = [SupportCatagory].[PK_SupportCatagory]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[ApplicationId] = [Application].[PK_Application]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[Deleted] != 1) 
AND [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate] >= '1/1/1990' 
ORDER BY [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate] DESC
```

This is what is being returned:

[image]

This is nearly correct. I only want it to return one copy of PK_NonScrumStory though and I can't figure out how. Essentially, I only want it to return one copy so one of the top two rows would not be returned.

Comment: What do you mean by one copy ?

Comment: Sorry, Only 1 with the same PK_NonScrumStory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by the NonScrumStore columns, and then aggregate the other columns like this:

```
SELECT [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], 
       [NonScrumStory].[Description], 
       MAX( [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate]), 
       MAX( [Application].[AppName]), 
       MAX([SupportCatagory].[Catagory]), 
       MAX([DailyTaskHours].[PK_DailyTaskHours]), 
       [NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] 
FROM [NonScrumStory], 
     [DailyTaskHours], 
     [Application], 
     [SupportCatagory] 
WHERE ([NonScrumStory].[UserId] = 26) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] = [DailyTaskHours].[NonScrumStoryId]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[CatagoryId] = [SupportCatagory].[PK_SupportCatagory]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[ApplicationId] = [Application].[PK_Application]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[Deleted] != 1) 
AND [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate] >= '1/1/1990'
group by [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description],[NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory]   
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Getting the following error: Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Column "DailyTaskHours.ActivityDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You are getting multiple rows because NonScrumStory table has a 1 to many relationship with some of those other tables.  So, I grouped by all the NonScrumStory columns, and then had to aggregate the other columns.  I just selected the MAX for each.  That's how you can force the 1 to MANY back to a 1 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it seems DISTINCT should have solved your issue but if not you could use the ROW_NUMBER function.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] ORDER BY [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate] DESC) AS RowNum,
[NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description], [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate], [Application].[AppName], [SupportCatagory].[Catagory], [DailyTaskHours].[PK_DailyTaskHours],n [NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] 
FROM [NonScrumStory], [DailyTaskHours], [Application], [SupportCatagory] 
WHERE ([NonScrumStory].[UserId] = 26) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] = [DailyTaskHours].[NonScrumStoryId]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[CatagoryId] = [SupportCatagory].[PK_SupportCatagory]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[ApplicationId] = [Application].[PK_Application]) 
AND ([NonScrumStory].[Deleted] != 1) 
AND [DailyTaskHours].[ActivityDate] >= '1/1/1990' 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNum = 1 ORDER BY [ActivityDate] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add DISTINCT to your query that should solve your problem. Like so

SELECT **DISTINCT** [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description],...

Comment: This isn't working, I believe it's because the data is coming from multiple tables.